# incorrect Navigation bar background image coloring for iphone 12 mini

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigationbar

I'm setting the image of the navigation bar to a gradient. This works perfectly on all models except for iPhone 12 mini.

I've tried calling this on my main view controller in ViewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, and ViewDidLoad

[image]

Here's what it looks like on all other models

[image]

```
    func setNavGradiant(){
    guard let navigationController = self.navigationController else {print("❇️♊️>>>\(#file) \(#line): guard let failed<<<"); return}
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    var updatedFrame = navigationController.navigationBar.bounds
    updatedFrame.size.height += UIApplication.shared.windows[0].windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0

   
   
    gradientLayer.frame = updatedFrame
    gradientLayer.colors = [ #colorLiteral(red: 0.4392156899, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1).cgColor,  #colorLiteral(red: 0.2196078449, green: 0.007843137719, blue: 0.8549019694, alpha: 1).cgColor] // start color and end color
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0) // vertical gradient start
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
    gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9579688907, green: 0.9579688907, blue: 0.9579688907, alpha: 1))]
}
```

Comment: Where and when are you calling this?

Comment: I just edited explaining where this is.. Ive tried viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, and ViewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have better results by subclassing `UINavigationController`:

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        gradient.frame = navigationBar.bounds
        
        gradient.colors = [ #colorLiteral(red: 0.4392156899, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1).cgColor,  #colorLiteral(red: 0.2196078449, green: 0.007843137719, blue: 0.8549019694, alpha: 1).cgColor] // start color and end color
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0) // vertical gradient start
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        
        if let image = getImageFrom(gradientLayer: gradient) {
            navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        }

    }

    func getImageFrom(gradientLayer:CAGradientLayer) -> UIImage? {
        var gradientImage:UIImage?
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.frame.size)
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            gradientLayer.render(in: context)
            gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero, resizingMode: .stretch)
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return gradientImage
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
```

after your setup is done. Should work without dispatching to main thread, but I had previously caught issues of things called from lifecycle methods not being on the main thread. So another thing to check is to make sure you are running the updates on the main thread.